# .getDownloadUrl() gives me error - Android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to put data to firebase database but .getDownloadUrl() gives me error - Can not resolve method, Am i missing something? I think i have to do it other way

[image: Android Studio Screenshot]

Please help me by modifying this code and answering.

Here is the code -

```
StorageReference file = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("message_images").child(messageId + ".jpg");

            file.putFile(url).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task)
                {
                    if(task.isSuccessful())
                    {
                        String imageUrl = task.getResult().getDownloadUrl().toString(); //here is the error

                        Map messageMap = new HashMap();
                        messageMap.put("message", imageUrl);
                        messageMap.put("type", "image");
                        messageMap.put("from", currentUserId);
                        messageMap.put("to", otherUserId);
                        messageMap.put("timestamp", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);

                        HashMap<String, String> notificationData = new HashMap<>();
                        notificationData.put("from", currentUserId);
                        notificationData.put("type", "message");

                        Map userMap = new HashMap();
                        userMap.put("Messages/" + currentUserId + "/" + otherUserId + "/" + messageId, messageMap);
                        userMap.put("Messages/" + otherUserId + "/" + currentUserId + "/" + messageId, messageMap);

                        userMap.put("Chat/" + currentUserId + "/" + otherUserId + "/message", "You have sent a picture.");
                        userMap.put("Chat/" + currentUserId + "/" + otherUserId + "/timestamp", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
                        userMap.put("Chat/" + currentUserId + "/" + otherUserId + "/seen", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);

                        userMap.put("Chat/" + otherUserId + "/" + currentUserId + "/message", "Has send you a picture.");
                        userMap.put("Chat/" + otherUserId + "/" + currentUserId + "/timestamp", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
                        userMap.put("Chat/" + otherUserId + "/" + currentUserId + "/seen", 0);

                        userMap.put("Notifications/" + otherUserId + "/" + notificationId, notificationData);

                        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().updateChildren(userMap, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference)
                            {
                                sendButton.setEnabled(true);

                                if(databaseError != null)
                                {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "sendMessage(): updateChildren failed: " + databaseError.getMessage());
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: I didn't understand that can you provide an exact code for my case please?

Answer (score 1):

You should add [**`getStorage()`**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference#getStorage())

```
String imageUrl = task.getResult().getStorage().getDownloadUrl().toString();
```

Comment: Actually it does not gives me a error but the image is not getting submitted on firebase.

Comment: @user9157668 need debugging for that.

Comment: Should i provide you something?

Comment: Ohk, I will create another one

Answer (score 1):

correct code is:
`task.getResult().getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl();`

Comment: if you are using newest library versions it should work. I am using it in my project.

Comment: you also need to add  `.addOnCompleteListener` after `.getDownloadUrl()`. And result is going to be your url link